# Android HorizontalScrollView doesn't scroll very well

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a problem with the scrolling of horizontalscrollview. It doesn't scroll very well when I swipe with my finger inside it. This is my layout :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/progress_bar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annonce_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/annonce_description"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/images_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I populate the images_container by ImageView like this :

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) this.rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.images_container);

    if (vg.getChildCount() == 0 && this.an.getSomeUrlsImage() !=null)
        for (String imageUrl : this.an.getSomeUrlsImage()) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(getActivity());

            img = ImageConfig.setDefaultConfigForImageView(img);

            this.imageDownloader.download(imageUrl, img);

            vg.addView(img);
        }
```

This is the ImageConfig class code :

```
public class ImageConfig {

    public static ImageView setDefaultConfigForImageView(ImageView v){

        v.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        v.setMinimumHeight(156);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Have you any idea to resolve this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is your scrolling problem related to the images appearing? Your problem could be that when the image gets downloaded and assigned to the imageView the imageView requests a layout pass for all your view hierarchy and that makes your scrollview behave badly

Comment: So,have you any idea in order to improve the scrolling ? Thank you

Comment: Well first try to understand if that's the case using static resource images for a test. Then probably you can try to use fixed sized imageviews and override the onLayout method to do nothing if the size didn't change